# How to parse bundle data received from facebook in Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am creating `webDialog` for sending friend request on `facebook`.I am able to create web-dialog and send friend request but I don't know to parse bundle date.Once request is send and if there is no error I am getting the response of `facebook` in the following manner **Bundle[{to[0]=100005695389624, to[1]=100002812207673, request=333965433373671}]**.I want to parse this data.How can I do this.

I am able to get `request` from the above data but how can i get the `to` parameter from it.If any one is having any idea then please let me know.

I tried in the following manner.

```
 final String requestId = values.getString("request"); // This value retrieved properly. 
 char at[] = values.getString("to").toCharArray(); // returns null
 String str[] = values.getStringArray("to");       //  returns null
 String s = values.getString("to");                // return null
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am creating `WebDialog` for inviting friends of `facebook`.In response of that I am getting the values in bundle in following format.

`Bundle[{to[0]=10045667789624, to[1]=1353002812207673, request=1234555}]`

So I was having issues in parsing data of the bundle.I resolved it in the following manner.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Message from Android App.");

WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(ChatRoom.this,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                   @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) {

                        if( values != null)
                        {
                            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                            ArrayList<String> friendsId = new ArrayList<String>(); 

                            int i = 0;
                            String to;

                            do {

                                to = values.getString("to[" +i + "]");  

                                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(to)) 
                                {
                                    friendsId.add(to);
                                }

                                i++;

                            } while (to != null);

                            if (requestId != null) {

                                Toast.makeText(ChatRoom.this.getApplicationContext(),"Request sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } 

                            else {

                                Toast.makeText(ChatRoom.this.getApplicationContext(),"Request cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        toggle();
                    }
                })
                .build();

        requestsDialog.show();
```

Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it will work, but try viewing the to array as just a String.

```
   final String requestId = values.getString("request"); 
   final String to0 = values.getString("to[0]");
   final String to1 = values.getString("to[1]");
```

If you don't know how many of these to strings you have, you could create a simple while loop and continue until it returns null. It's not an elegant solution, but it's the only one I can come up with right now. If you know more about the bundle, you can probably find a better solution.

```
ArrayList<String> to = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;
while (true) {
   String x = values.getString("to["+i+"]");
   if (x == null) {
       break;
   } else {
       to.add(x);
       i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I am getting that `to` parameter dynamically i.e. I don't know the size of that array so won't work at runtime :(

Comment: But it is not useful because I don't know the size of that array so how can I recognize how many users I have send the request.

Comment: A simple while loop could do it. Though I imagine there are better solutions.

Comment: @Oxidater have tried this just give one try.And u can't declare the string array like the way u mentioned.

Comment: My bad, I wrote it straight here. I replaced it. It's the idea that counts though, you can figure out the actual code yourself.

Comment: Thanks budy for the idea I have posted my code.I can not accept the answer but for giving me idea i can surely give +1 :)