# How to extract a value from a facebook invite friends onComplete() response

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, bundle, facebook-invite

I am implementing Facebook friends invite in my android app and I need to get to how many friends user sent app request so that I can award him some points.

What I have done so far is as below

```
WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,
    sessiob, params)).setOnCompleteListener(
        new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) {
                if (error != null) {

                } else {

                    final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                    final String[] requestArr1 = values.getStringArray("to");
                    if (requestId != null) {

                        Log.e("RequestId1",requestId + "\n" + values.toString());
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    }).build();
```

And the Bundle value I am getting is `Bundle[{to[0]=808411111111111,to[1]=151584774222222, request=879734911111111}]`

While my above code `final String requestId = values.getString("request");` working fine however `values.getStringArray("to");` giving me Null.

I want to know value `"to"` inside the Bundle is a StringArray or not and if yes then what's wrong in my extraction process.

Comment: I think `"to"` is not an array rather `to[0]` and `to[1]` are individual strings. 
I got my answer referring to the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494940/how-to-parse-bundle-data-received-from-facebook-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494940/how-to-parse-bundle-data-received-from-facebook-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example you will find your all answers

[Simple facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)

Comment: Can you please tell me what's wrong I am doing here?
Because I am already able to send invitation and also getting response using this method. So my problem is to find the number of recipient only.

Comment: I think `"to"` is not an array rather `to[0]` and `to[1]` are individual strings. 
I got my answer referring to the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494940/how-to-parse-bundle-data-received-from-facebook-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494940/how-to-parse-bundle-data-received-from-facebook-in-android)